# How to get full value from power function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using **power** function in one of my calculation like:

```
select power(1.01,15)
```

which gives me result **1.16**, but from this result(**1.16**), I am unable to get the actual output in my further calculation. I am getting the actual result if this power function gives me the result **1.16096896**. I don't know why I am getting rounded figures(**1.16**), I actually want output(**1.16096896**). Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to cast first value to **numeric**

```
select power(cast(1.01 as numeric(19,8)),15)
```

gives you **1.16096896**

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20400/0)

---

cast to **float** example

```
 select power(cast(1.01 as float),15)
```

gives you **1.16096895537**

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20401/0)

Comment: Why can't we cast it as float?

Comment: select power(cast(1.01 as float),15)
I use this query and it is working fine.